# Create Structured Numpy Array with Different Types

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I have the following unstructured data (read from a csv).

```
data = [[b'id' b'datetime' b'anomaly_length' b'affected_sensors' b'reason']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:09' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:10' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:11' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:12' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:13' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:14' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:15' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:16' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']
 [b'1' b'2019-12-20 08:17' b'26' b'all' b'Open Windows']]
 ...
```

I currently create structured arrays by using the following code:

```
labels_id = np.array(data[1:,0], dtype=int)
labels = [dt.datetime.strptime(date.decode("utf-8"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for date in np.array(data[1:,1])]
labels_length = np.array(data[1:,2], dtype=int)
```

This code is necessary because I need data with the correct datatype. In the function, I pass all the arrays and access them by index. I don't like this solution but because the function is called multiple times I don't want to cast the data inside the function each time.

Origin function code:

```
def special_find(labels_id, labels, labels_length):
    for i, id in enumerate(labels_id):
       print(id)
       print(labels[i])
       print(labels_length[i])
...
```

Expected: I want to have a structured array which only contains the needed columns:

```
structured_data = [[1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 9) b'2019-12-20 08:09' 26],
 [1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 10) 26],
 [1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 11) 26],
 [1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 12) 26],
 [1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 13) 26],
 [1 datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 20, 8, 14) 26],
...
```

I know I could concat all the created arrays but I don't think this is a good solution. Instead, I am searching for something like this:

```
structured_data = np.array(data[1:, 0:3], dtype=...)
```

UPDATE: here are some values for a csv file

```
id,datetime,anomaly_length,affected_sensors,reason
1,2019-12-20 08:09,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:10,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:11,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:12,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:13,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:14,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:15,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:16,26,all,Open Windows
1,2019-12-20 08:17,26,all,Open Windows
```

Comment: Use Pandas. NumPy loses lots of its usefulness when your data isn't all of the same type.

Comment: @Seb can you give me a code example?

Comment: It might be easier to get the  structured array when reading the csv.  You can specify `dtype=None` or your own `dtype`

Comment: The `pandas` `read_csv` is powerful and fast.  You could use ``to_records` to get a structured array from the dataframe.  Regardless handing that date/time column can be tricky, since possible types include string, `datetime` objects and `np.datetime64`.

Comment: I'll second what @Seb suggested, use Pandas. Can you share at least part of your data? See: [mcve].

Comment: @AMC I added some example data for a csv file. Furthermore I solved my problem by combining pandas `read_csv` with `converters` parameter and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined the `read_csv` from pandas together with `converters:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

filename = './data.csv'

to_date = lambda value: (dt.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
values = pd.read_csv(filename, converters={'datetime': to_date})
print(values.dtypes)


>>> OUTPUT:
>>> id                           int64
>>> datetime            datetime64[ns]
>>> anomaly_length               int64
>>> affected_sensors            object
>>> reason                      object
>>> dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already converted the columns to NumPy arrays of the correct data type, it is easy to create a Pandas `DataFrame` from them, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': labels_id,
    'datetime': labels,
    'anomaly_length': labels_length
})
```

```py
>>> df
   id            datetime  anomaly_length
0   1 2019-12-20 08:09:00              26
1   1 2019-12-20 08:10:00              26
2   1 2019-12-20 08:11:00              26
3   1 2019-12-20 08:12:00              26
4   1 2019-12-20 08:13:00              26
5   1 2019-12-20 08:14:00              26
6   1 2019-12-20 08:15:00              26
7   1 2019-12-20 08:16:00              26
8   1 2019-12-20 08:17:00              26
```

The [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) have a good introduction on how to work with these objects.

Comment: Is it possible to use pandas directly for reading the csv and filling the dataframe?

Comment: @KevinWallis yes, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your csv file with:

```
In [23]: cat stack59665655.txt                                                  
id, datetime, anomaly_length, affected_sensors, reason
1, 2019-12-20 08:09, 26, all, Open Windows
1, 2019-12-20 08:10, 26, all, Open Windows
1, 2019-12-20 08:11, 26, all, Open Windows
```

With `pandas` I can read it with:

```
In [24]: data = pd.read_csv('stack59665655.txt')                                
In [25]: data                                                                   
Out[25]: 
   id           datetime   anomaly_length  affected_sensors         reason
0   1   2019-12-20 08:09               26               all   Open Windows
1   1   2019-12-20 08:10               26               all   Open Windows
2   1   2019-12-20 08:11               26               all   Open Windows
In [26]: data.dtypes                                                            
Out[26]: 
id                    int64
 datetime            object
 anomaly_length       int64
 affected_sensors    object
 reason              object
dtype: object
```

The `object` columns contain strings.  I suspect pandas has a way of converting that `datetime` string column to `datetime` objects or `np.datetime64`.

The simple conversion to array, produces an object dtype array:

```
In [27]: data.to_numpy()                                                        
Out[27]: 
array([[1, ' 2019-12-20 08:09', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows'],
       [1, ' 2019-12-20 08:10', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows'],
       [1, ' 2019-12-20 08:11', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows']],
      dtype=object)
```

`to_records` produces a `record` array, a variant on a structured array.  Note the compound dtype:

```
In [28]: data.to_records()                                                      
Out[28]: 
rec.array([(0, 1, ' 2019-12-20 08:09', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows'),
           (1, 1, ' 2019-12-20 08:10', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows'),
           (2, 1, ' 2019-12-20 08:11', 26, ' all', ' Open Windows')],
          dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('id', '<i8'), (' datetime', 'O'), (' anomaly_length', '<i8'), (' affected_sensors', 'O'), (' reason', 'O')])
```

Instead, using `genfromtxt` with it's auto-dtype mode:

```
In [29]: data1 =np.genfromtxt('stack59665655.txt',dtype=None, names=True,delimit
    ...: er=',',encoding=None, autostrip=True)                                  
In [30]: data1                                                                  
Out[30]: 
array([(1, '2019-12-20 08:09', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows'),
       (1, '2019-12-20 08:10', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows'),
       (1, '2019-12-20 08:11', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows')],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('datetime', '<U16'), ('anomaly_length', '<i8'), ('affected_sensors', '<U3'), ('reason', '<U12')])
```

I could convert the `datetime` field with:

```
In [31]: data1['datetime']                                                      
Out[31]: 
array(['2019-12-20 08:09', '2019-12-20 08:10', '2019-12-20 08:11'],
      dtype='<U16')
In [32]: data1['datetime'].astype('datetime64[m]')                              
Out[32]: 
array(['2019-12-20T08:09', '2019-12-20T08:10', '2019-12-20T08:11'],
      dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

Changing this in-place actually requires defining a new dtype.

Or I could construct a custom dtype, for example by modifying the one deduced for `data1`:

```
In [45]: dt = data1.dtype.descr                                                 
In [46]: dt[1]=('datetime', 'datetime64[m]')                                    
In [47]: dt= np.dtype(dt)                                                       
In [48]: dt                                                                     
Out[48]: dtype([('id', '<i8'), ('datetime', '<M8[m]'), ('anomaly_length', '<i8'), ('affected_sensors', '<U3'), ('reason', '<U12')])

In [49]: data2 =np.genfromtxt('stack59665655.txt',dtype=dt, names=True,delimiter
    ...: =',',encoding=None, autostrip=True)                                    
In [50]: data2                                                                  
Out[50]: 
array([(1, '2019-12-20T08:09', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows'),
       (1, '2019-12-20T08:10', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows'),
       (1, '2019-12-20T08:11', 26, 'all', 'Open Windows')],
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('datetime', '<M8[m]'), ('anomaly_length', '<i8'), ('affected_sensors', '<U3'), ('reason', '<U12')])
```

To use `datetime` objects, I'd have to use a `converter` in `genfromtxt.

Comment: _I suspect pandas has a way of converting that datetime string column to datetime objects or np.datetime64_ `.read_csv()` has a `parse_dates` parameter, that might work?

Comment: thanks for the answer I actually combined `read_csv` with `converters`